# Keydown function not working with input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

I've got a simple log-in page that I hid an Easter-egg on for the team. Basically, it's a mostly blank page with:

```
<form id="X" method="post" action="Y">
    <input id="Z" name="Z" type="text" maxlength="99" />
    <button type="submit" class="">Make the Jump</button>
</form>
```

The Easter-egg is:

```
function getFun() {
  var max = 1971;
  var rando = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
  var getFunURL = 'https://xkcd.now.sh/' + rando;
  var comicHTML;
  var GetComic = $.ajax({
    url: getFunURL,
    method: 'get',
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    var title = data.safe_title;
    var imgURL = data.img;
    comicHTML = '<img src="' + imgURL + '" />';
  })
  .fail(function() {
    comicHTML = '<div>No dice on the comic. It failed to load.</div>';
  })
  .always(function() {
    $("#easterEgg").html(comicHTML);
    $("#easterEgg").show();
  });
}
var allowedKeys = {
  37: 'left',
  38: 'up',
  39: 'right',
  40: 'down',
  65: 'a',
  66: 'b'
};
var konamiCode = ['up', 'up', 'down', 'down', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'b', 'a'];
var konamiCodePosition = 0;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  var key = allowedKeys[e.keyCode];
  var requiredKey = konamiCode[konamiCodePosition];
  if (key == requiredKey) {
    konamiCodePosition++;
    if (konamiCodePosition == konamiCode.length) {
      activateCheats();
      konamiCodePosition = 0;
    }
  } else {
    konamiCodePosition = 0;
  }
});
function activateCheats() {
  getFun();
}
```

When clicking into the blank space of the page (removing the cursor from being inside the input) and executing Konami, the comic loads. However, when the cursor is inside of the input, executing Konami does nothing.

**Why would the .keydown function not work when cursor is inside the input?**

Comment: `$(document).on('keydown', '*',  function(){...})` Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$("#Z").keydown(function(e) {
// write code here
});
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand my intent. I'd like a keydown, regardless of whether the cursor is inside input or not, to be able to trigger Konami. This code would limit the execution to keydown inside of the input, no?